# classify the units in Deep learning for image classification

Tags: classification, deep-learning, dbn

Suppose we have a database with 10 classes, and we do classification test on it by Deep Belief Network or Convolutional Neural Network. The question is that how we can understand which neurons in the last layer are related to which object? 
In one of the post, a person wrote " to understand which neurons are for an object like shoes and which ones are not you will put that all units in the last layer to another supervised classifier(this can be anything like multi-class-SVM or a soft-max-layer). I do not know how it should be done? I do need more expansion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 10 classes, make your last layer have 10 neurons and use the softmax activation function. This will make sure that they all lie between 0 and 1 and add up to 1. Then, simply use the index of the neuron with the largest value as your output class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem from my side is that, I heard deep learning shares the neurons for all objects, and this feature differs it with MLP, I think.   Please modify me if it is wrong. Would you please tell me how can I get some regions,  or pixels in the case of an object of interest with the last layer of deep learning? To some extend, I want to do some things to segment an image or cluster an object by deep learning.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into **class activation maps** which does something similar to what you are asking for. [Here](http://jacobcv.blogspot.in/2016/08/class-activation-maps-in-keras.html) is an insightful blog post explaining **CAM**s